# Strange vowel harmony in Arabic loanwords within Turkish—why could it be?

Tags: arabic, borrowing, turkish, irregularity

Some Arabic loanwords have a palatalised, for example, /lʲ/ in final position, and it is more understandable in the case of those words. However, some others go against vowel harmony for no apparent reason:

| Unpossessed | 1st person possessive | 2nd person possessive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rab | rabbim | rabbin |
| saat | saatim | saatin |
| harf | harfim | harfin |
| seyahat | seyahatim | seyahatin |

Some others have an epenthetic /i/, so one may say that to be influencing harmony, even after it disappears. Eg. vakit vaktim vaktin.

Why exactly would this occur? Wikipedia says that the absence of the Arabic letters forcing back-vowel pronunciation in Ottoman orthography cause the cases above, but that does not seem to explain this adequately, given letters like ف and ب possess no emphatic versions of their own.

Comment: “Rabbım, Rabbın” are also correct, but as a rule the vowel harmony rules _do not_ apply to loanwords.

Comment: You need to use double line breaks (= paragraph breaks), not double space + single line break (= forced line break) to get paragraphs, and tables must be in individual paragraph blocks to work.

Comment: The word _kitab_ 'book' violates harmony in a big way, but it's a very prominent word. I always made sure it appeared in morphology problems featuring harmony, because it **does** form predictably harmonic suffixes. As @YellowSky pointed out, loaned roots often don't follow harmony in their internal structure.

Comment: Vowel harmony applies to loanwords in that suffixing is done according to the adjacent vowel (kitap kitabım kitabın), and the examples cited above contradict even that. A quick look at the TDK's dictionary reveals that the forms violating harmony are standard, and indeed, the mere utterance of the words 'rabbım', 'rabbın' leaves me with a feeling that something is wrong.

Comment: My pet theory here is that the kasrah, being sounded like /ɯ/ with the uvulars/emphatics, and /i/ otherwise, has influenced Turkish inflection into contrasting eg. hak(kım) & hak(kim), along with affecting a myriad of other words used too frequently to have their dissenting /i/s levelled.